# Owl Carousal2 with items 1 and loop true

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel-2

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items: 1
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
</div>
<link href="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

**Console Error : TypeError: items[clones[(clones.length - 1)]] is undefined.**
this error due to only one item `div` and property loop `true` and item 1.
So. any solution at this situation. I know this type of Situation does not occurs but if any solutions please tell me Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 17):

Add onInitialize and check how many items the carousel contains. If the carousel has 1 or less items, set loop to false.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items: 1,
    onInitialize: function (event) {
        if ($('.owl-carousel .item').length <= 1) {
           this.settings.loop = false;
        }
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: you are right if item is one than loop false, but scenario is that item one and loop true is possible?

Comment: It should be possible, but it is a bug in the owl carousel.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: $('.owl-carousel .item').size() > 1 ? true:false,
    items: 1,
    margin:10,
    nav:true
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a very basic fix (on the owl.carousel.js file). Check my comment here 
https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1200#issuecomment-215254526

It's an extremely quick & dirty fix. That I'll try to enhance as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $(".owl-parent");
loop: owl.children().length > 1
```

Change the selector according to your needs.

This works too.

Answer (score 0):

Include `owl.carousel.min.css` file below the `jquery.min.js` file and also include those files at the bottom of the page.

Comment: that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dyxqeyox/)

is this the one you are looking for ?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello @Ashley u r right but at responsive but i want items:1 only and also <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div> only one. and loop property true. i know this type of situation does not occurs but in case.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if($(".owl-carousel").length > 0){
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,       
            nav: $(".owl-carousel > .item").length <= 1 ? false : true,
            dots: false,
            loop:$(".owl-carousel > .item").length <= 1 ? false : true,
            autoplay:true,
            navText: "",         
        });
    }
```